# iptables rule setup

Tags: iptables

I'm reading examples for iptables, and I've got a pre-written file I'm using for the server that meets most of my needs. The format it uses to accept traffic on port 80 (for apache) is:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Another webpage I've read uses the following format to accept traffic for SMTP

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 --sport 1024:65535 -d server.ip.address.here --dport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Which seems a lot more complex? Is it necessary, or could I simply do:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rule is more specific, thus theorically allowing less connections :

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 --sport 1024:65535 -d server.ip.address.here --dport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

With this rule the connection needs to be initiated by a client (port>=1024), on a specific IP (therefore a single interface), and the client can only initiate a new connection or use an already established one.

But this simpler rule, since less specific, allow any kind of connection, from any port, to any interface on the port 25.

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
```

Keep in mind that if you do not reinforce your firewall by using specific DROP rules, or iptables' policies (`-P`) to DROP all packets that aren't explicitely allowed, any ACCEPT rule will be useless.

Comment: [The basic IP tables ruleset](http://articles.slicehost.com/assets/2007/9/4/iptables.txt) I'm using denies anything not explicitly allowed so I think I'm okay on the DROP rules. You'd recommend the more specific rule, I'm assuming?

Comment: Well that depends on whether your server is really "at risk" or not. But let's face it, the specific rule isn't that complicated :p So yes, I would recommend it instead of the simpler one :-)